# What is the time complexity ( Big Oh, Omega and Theta ) for this algorithm for deciding whether a point is inside a triangle?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

The algorithm is implemented in python 3.
It decides whether a point is inside a triangle or not by calculating the areas formed by the point and the different coordinates of the triangle.
Also are there better/faster algorithms for this?

```
import math


#FUnction for calculating area
def CalcArea ( a1, b1, c1 ):
  a = CalcLength (a1, b1)
  b = CalcLength (a1, c1)
  c = CalcLength (b1, c1)
  s = ( a+b+c ) / 2
  return math.sqrt( s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c) )

#Function for calculating length of line segment
def CalcLength ( a1, b1 ):
  return math.sqrt( ((b1[0]-a1[0])**2) + ((b1[1]-a1[1])**2)  )

#Main function to check if point is inside triangle based on areas
def TotalAreaChk ( a, b, c, p ):
  totalArea = CalcArea( a,b,p ) + CalcArea( a,c,p ) + CalcArea( b,c,p )
  TriangleArea = CalcArea( a, b, c )

  if totalArea > TriangleArea:
    print ("The point does not lies inside the triangle")
  else:
    print ("The point lies inside the triangle")

#Declaring the coords 

A = ( 1.0, 2.0 )
B = ( 2.0, 2.0 )
C = ( 1.5, 1.5 )
P = ( 1.5, 1.8 )

TotalAreaChk(A, B, C, P)
```

Comment: Small tip: Instead of doing `math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`, use `math.hypot(dx, dx)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(N) notation tells us how the time required to execute an algorithm scales with the size N of its input. What is the size of the input in this case? How would you scale it?

For example, you might generalize your algorithm to test whether a given point is inside a polygon with N vertices. Then it would make sense to ask how the running time of the algorithm scales with N.  Or you might generalize to allowing the triangle or polygon to exist in a d-dimensional space, and then you might ask about the running time O(d).

**Hint**: If the running time of your algorithm is the same for all inputs, how would you describe this in O(N) notation?